# Increasing the tickrate of an ErrorListLogPlot

Tags: plotting

I'm new to Mathematica and am trying to do an `ErrorListLogPlot` using the "ErrorBarLogPlots" package (from [the Wolfram Library](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6747/ErrorBarLogPlots.zip?file_id=6147)) for a graphical evaluation.

```
    Needs["ErrorBarLogPlots`"]; 
    ErrorListLogPlot[
     {
      {
      {{1/8.85, 43.59`}, ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]},
      {{1/11.30, 38.19`}, ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]},
      {{1/12.4, 33.48`}, ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]},
      {{1/13.5, 29.84`}, ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]},
      {{1/14.75, 25.74`}, ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]},
      {{1/15.6, 23.44`}, ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]},
      {{1/16.00, 22.61`}, ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]},
      {{1/16.6, 21.70`}, ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]},
      {{1/17.3, 20.44`}, ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]},
      {{1/19, 2.3, 17.74`}, ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]},
      {{1/19.85, 17.00`}, ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]},
      {{1/20.0, 16.92`}, ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]},
      {{1/18.5, 18.68`}, ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]}}
   },
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> GrayLevel[.9], 
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(T\)]\)", "t"}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I'd like to let Mathematica show more ticks on the y-axes, at the moment there are two.

May there's anybody who can help? :)

Edit:

Thanks a lot! :)

I got some nice results by combining it with the table function, and it makes my life so much easier.

```
Needs["ErrorBarLogPlots`"];
ErrorListLogPlot[
{
  {

   {{1/282.05, 43.59`}, ErrorBar[0, 0.42]},
   {{1/284.50, 38.19`}, ErrorBar[0, 0.42]},
   {{1/285.60, 33.48`}, ErrorBar[0, 0.42]},
   {{1/286.70, 29.84`}, ErrorBar[0, 0.42]},
   {{1/287.95, 25.74`}, ErrorBar[0, 0.42]},
   {{1/288.80, 23.44`}, ErrorBar[0, 0.42]},
   {{1/289.20, 22.61`}, ErrorBar[0, 0.42]},
   {{1/289.80, 21.70`}, ErrorBar[0, 0.42]},
   {{1/290.50, 20.44`}, ErrorBar[0, 0.42]},
   {{1/292.40, 17.74`}, ErrorBar[0, 0.42]},
   {{1/293.05, 17.00`}, ErrorBar[0, 0.42]},
   {{1/293.20, 16.92`}, ErrorBar[0, 0.42]},
   {{1/291.70, 18.68`}, ErrorBar[0, 0.42]}}
 },
 AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(T\)]\)", "t"}, 
 Ticks -> {Table[n, {n, 0, 0.0036, 0.00001}], Table[n, {n, 0, 40}]}, 
 GridLines -> {Table[n, {n, 0, 0.0036, 0.000001}], Table[n, {n, 0, 100, 0.5}]}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: `Ticks -> {Automatic, {20, 25, 30, 35, 40}}` and many variations.  See `ticks` (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ticks.html). Also try: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ticks

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. In the picture that I inserted above  I counted 7 ticks on the y-axis. Do you really have only 2 ticks  or do you mean something different with the word "ticks"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that you wanted to have more *tick labels* because the number of ticks is already more than two. You can do that by playing with the `Ticks` option, and perhaps using `PlotRange`, as follows

```
Needs["ErrorBarLogPlots`"];
ErrorListLogPlot[{{{{1/8.85, 43.59`}, 
    ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]}, {{1/11.30, 38.19`}, 
    ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]}, {{1/12.4, 33.48`}, 
    ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]}, {{1/13.5, 29.84`}, 
    ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]}, {{1/14.75, 25.74`}, 
    ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]}, {{1/15.6, 23.44`}, 
    ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]}, {{1/16.00, 22.61`}, 
    ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]}, {{1/16.6, 21.70`}, 
    ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]}, {{1/17.3, 20.44`}, 
    ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]}, {{1/19, 2.3, 17.74`}, 
    ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]}, {{1/19.85, 17.00`}, 
    ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]}, {{1/20.0, 16.92`}, 
    ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]}, {{1/18.5, 18.68`}, 
    ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-0.42, 0.42}]}}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> GrayLevel[.9], 
 AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(T\)]\)", "t"}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40}}, 
 PlotRange -> {5, 50}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You're right, I was talking about the tick labels, thank you!